# Remote error from mongot :: caused by :: query has expanded into too many sub-queries internally: maxClauseCount is set to 1024

Tags: mongodb, lucene, mongodb-atlas-search

I'm using MongoDB's Atlas Search `$search` aggregation pipeline stage. I'm getting the following error:

`Remote error from mongot :: caused by :: query has expanded into too many sub-queries internally: maxClauseCount is set to 1024`

This seems to be occurring because of the default value of Lucene's [maxClauseCount][1] variable which is set to 1024.

Here's my code:

```
const { Restaurant } = require('../models');

Restaurant.aggregate({
  $search: {
    index: 'default',
    compound: {
        should: {
           {
             autocomplete: {
               query: filter.searchText,
               path: 'name',
             },
           }

          ..._.map(mealMatchedRestaurantIds, (id) => {
            return {
              equals: {
                path: '_id',
                value: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
              },
            }
          })
         },

         minimumShouldMatch = 1;
    }
  }
});
```

I'm dynamically generating the 'equals' clauses from the `mealMatchedRestaurantIds` array. The length of this array is exceeding 1024 which is resulting in the `maxClauseCount` value to be exceeded.
[1]: https://github.com/apache/lucene/search?q=maxClauseCount

Does MongoDB provide any API to override the value of this variable? Or is there a better way of designing this search query (other than chunking it into multiple queries)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have over 1024 terms in a compound query, which is a lucene boolean query, you need to pursue a different query. If `searchTerm` can be smaller than 1024 terms you will be fine.